# I'm a bit confused...why is in_reply_to getting linked to in_reply_to_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I defined a new column in the Table "microposts" as such:

```
class AddInReplyToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :microposts, :in_reply_to_id, :integer
  end
end
```

The column is "in_reply_to_id", the relationship with the user's table is as follows:

```
belongs_to :in_reply_to, class_name: "User"
```

And it works!
And that's what confuses me, WHY does it work? Shouldn't it be "in_reply_to_id" instead of just "in_reply_to" ?

Comment: it's making relation to "in_reply_to" object by primary key. By default primary key equals to association_name + _id

Comment: Hmm...so by saying "belongs_to :user" I'm basically saying User.Id = Micropost.user_id, and so by specifying the class "User", I'm saying User.Id = Micropost.in_reply_to_id, correct?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right. The associations connect the objects, not the values of their ids. You wouldn't want something to belong to a user's id, because in some (most) cases, the id is just an int. The integer 7 conceptually would never "possess" another object.

Comment: Much clearer now, thank you both.